# What is the cleanest way to group by and conditionally transform data within a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas (0.25.3) and Python (3.7.4). I am working with a DataFrame similar to **df1** below.  I need to transform the "Hours" and "Wages" fields into the "Gross Hours", "Gross Wages", "Regular Wages" fields conditionally based on the value of the "Pay Code" field in the same DataFrame.  I also need to group by "Check Date".

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {
                        "Pay Code" : ["1","4","OCH","3","3"],
                        "Check Date" : ["2019-01-04","2019-01-04","2019-01-04","2019-01-04","2019-01-18"],
                        "Pay Start Date" : ["2018-12-15","2018-12-15","2018-12-15","2018-12-15","2018-12-29"],
                        "Pay End Date" : ["2018-12-28","2018-12-28","2018-12-28","2018-12-28","2019-01-11"],
                        "Pay Code Description" : ["REGULAR PAY","HOLIDAY PAY","ON CALL HOURLY","VACATION PAY","VACATION PAY"],
                        "Hours" : [46.0,16.0,152.0,18.0,19.5],
                        "Wages" : [1226.58,426.64,63.33,479.98,530.38],
                        "Gross Hours" : ["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],
                        "Regular Wages" : ["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"],
                        "Overtime Wages" : ["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"]
                  } )
```

Lets say I have static lists used as reference to determine which column the values should be transformed into.

```
GrossHours = ['1','2','3']

RegularWages = ['1','3','4']

OvertimeWages = ['2','OCH']
```

The desired **result** will be this DataFrame

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame( {
                        "Check Date" : ["2019-01-04","2019-01-18"],
                        "Pay Start Date" : ["2018-12-15","2018-12-29"],
                        "Pay End Date" : ["2018-12-28","2019-01-11"],
                        "Hours" : [232,19.5],
                        "Wages" : [2196.53,530.38],
                        "Gross Hours" : [64.0,19.5],
                        "Regular Wages" : [2133.2,530.38],
                        "Overtime Wages" : [63.33,"NaN"]
                  } )
```

What am I trying?
I've tried applying tons of lambda funtions to **df1** that give me results as desired, but I'm not certain how to get these resulting objects back to the original DataFrame df1 cleanly.  Is the only option to make a bunch of intermediary DataFrames that are then Joined or Merged back onto the original which is then **groupby**'ed again?

```
g1 = df1.groupby(["Check Date"])

g1.apply(lambda x: x[x['Pay Code'].isin(GrossHours)]['Hours'].astype(float).sum())

Check Date
2019-01-04    64.0
2019-01-18    19.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I don't understand "Lets say I have static lists used as reference to determine which column the values should be transformed into." Can you expand on that? also your code doesn't work with your sample dataset. Oh and you've put all your numeric values as strings.

Comment: @Datanovice you're right, I left one line out of my example code -- the groupby line.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Datanovice I've edited to correct the error now.

As for the "static lists", they will be used as shown in the lambda function to determine which field in "df_result" the values will be transformed into.  I.E., the "GrossHours" list will all be included in df_result['Gross Hours'],  "RegularWages" list will all be included in df_result['Regular Wages'].

Comment: For example -- Gross Hours -- df_result['Gross Hours'] only includes 46.0 and 18.0 in the sum of 64.0, since df1['Pay Code'] of "1" and "3" are the only values included in the .isin(GrossHours) evaluation inside the Lambda.

Comment: maybe `df1.loc[df1['Pay Code'].isin(GrossHours)].groupby('Check Date')['Hours','Wages'].sum()` I'm not sure how you get to your regular wages & overtime wages outcomes tho?

Comment: @Datanovice see my answer if you're curious.  I am able to get what I want out of this, but its not what I'd consider graceful.  Still hoping someone with some experience here has a more "Pythonic" way.

Answer (score 0):

First, I set up a list of tuples to iterate over.

```
transformations = [('Gross_Hours', ['1','2','3']), ('Regular_Wages', ['1','3','4']), ('Overtime_Wages', ['2','OCH'])]
```

I also defined the structure of the output dataframe I expect.

```
result_dataframe_fields = ['Check Date', 'Pay Start Date','Pay End Date','Gross Hours', 'Regular Wages', 'Overtime Wages']
```

By applying a suggestion by @Datanovice to a which was similar to the path I was already down, I ended up with this which is about as clean and readable as I can get it.

```
# Instatiate result dataframe
df_result = df1.groupby(result_dataframe_fields).sum().reset_index()

for t_ix, t_list in transformations:
    # Create aggregated set to populate result dataframe
    if t_ix == 'Gross_Hours':
        g1 = df1.loc[df1['Pay Code'].isin(t_list)].groupby('Check Date')['Hours'].agg(temp_col_name='sum')
        g2 = g1.reset_index()
        g2.columns = ['Check Date', t_ix]
    else:
        g1 = df1.loc[df1['Pay Code'].isin(t_list)].groupby('Check Date')['Wages'].agg(temp_col_name='sum')
        g2 = g1.reset_index()
        g2.columns = ['Check Date', t_ix]

    #Handle the .agg() column naming limitation (no spaces on list agg)
    colsg2 = g2.columns
    colsg2 = colsg2.map(lambda x: x.replace('_', ' ') if isinstance(x, (str)) else x)
    g2.columns = colsg2

    # Dataframe copy that will update result dataframe
    update_df = g2.copy()

    df_result.update(update_df)
```

[Result Image From Jupyter Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2t4t.png)

I still hope this isn't the best answer, as my actual application is far larger than this and looks rather hideous blown out to my "real code" scale.